# find div where title equals something

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="subjectissueref"><div id="subjectissue"> 
<div title="myDivTitle" class="cbs-Line1Link  ms-displayBlock"id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_9913c0d3_0331_4643_8d90_82268670a0f7_csr1_2lines_line1">
<b>Subject :</b> myDivTitle</div> 
<div title="anotherDivTitle" class="cbs-Line1Link  ms-displayBlock"id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_9913c0d3_0331_4643_8d90_82268670a0f7_csr1_2lines_line6"
><b>Issue :</b> anotherDivTitle</div></div>
 <div title="53" class="cbs-Line1Link  ms-displayBlock" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_9913c0d3_0331_4643_8d90_82268670a0f7_csr1_2lines_line7" style="float: right;">
<b>Ref :</b> #53</div></div>
```

I have this bit of code, and I want to use javascript to find the element where title equals myDivTitle

```
$('#subjectissureref').find('div[title=myDivTitle]')
```

Comment: $("div[title='kjjjjjjjjjjhh']")

Comment: Try `jQuery('#subjectissueref div[title="jkjjjjjjjjjjhh"]');`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_equal_value.asp

Comment: @user3616725 Don't read on w3schools.com. Try this http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: @user3616725 I updated your question, please use meaningful names next time to avoid downvotes

Comment: @algorhythm , why ? w3schools is also proper  , also it gives jQuery , html certifications !! its big organization like oracle to provide real life tough exams and then certi.

Comment: @algorhythm , you can check here anytime http://www.w3schools.com/cert/cert_jquery.asp  They offer certification.

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Yeah, as @Anton said: http://w3fools.com says all about http://www.w3schools.com/. By the way, I posted my own answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("div[title='myDivTitle']") // This will get div element
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
elem = $("div[title='myDivTitle']");
```

or

```
elem = $("div").prop('title', 'myDivTitle');
```

Answer (score 0):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gq0k5j1v/)**

```
$("div").each(function(){
    if($(this).prop('title')=="myDivTitle"){
        alert( "This div has title as myDivTitle");
    }
});
```

Comment: what kind of selector is this? Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: @anoop   ok. i create

Comment: @AnoopJoshi , created jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use `jQuery.filter(...)` with a custom function to get some special selections e.g.:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#subjectissueref .cbs-Line1Link').filter(function(index, elem) {
        return jQuery(elem).attr('title') == 'anotherDivTitle';
    }).css('background-color', 'green');
});
```

But in your case this is the shortest solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#subjectissueref div[title="myDivTitle"]').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/algorhythm/1o1hjw61/